# makefile option to generate latex documentation

Tags: latex, makefile, documentation-generation

I have a project that can be built via makefile, and I would like to add the ability for someone in the base directory to not only be able to build the executable via `make`, but also to build the documentation pdfs from LaTeX in a separate directory by typing `make docs` or something similar.
I only need one pass to generate the documentation, and there are no dependencies in the .tex files.
I don't have any experience with recursive makefiles, so any general resources would also be appreciated.

PS. I am not using noweb or similar systems, I simply have some source files and some separate .tex files.

Desired behavior:
`$ ls`
`docs/`
`Makefile`
`source1.cpp`
`source1.h`
`source2.cpp`
`source2.h`
`$ ls docs`
`Makefile`
`doc1.tex`
`$ make`
=my program gets compiled=
`$ make docs`
`$ ls docs`
`Makefile`
`doc1.tex`
`doc1.pdf`

Comment: Just use `cd docs && startDocGenerator.sh` as your action. The chdir will be transparently undone after the rule has terminated.

Comment: @Kilian: see my comment on dcolish's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213342/makefile-option-to-generate-latex-documentation/3213489#3213489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could easily just specify a command to execute the Makefile in the docs dir and run pdflatex -output-directory=DIR. So it would end up looking something like this:

In your toplevel Makefile add the rule

```
  docs:  
      $(MAKE) -C doc all
```

Then inside the doc dir you can add a Makefile with a rule like

```
%.pdf: %.tex 
      $(PDFLATEX PATH) --output-dir=$(DIR) $<
```

Comment: The issue is not how to write the makefile for my documentation, nor how to call it specifically from command line. What I want is for the base directory's makefile to recognize that I am asking for the documentation rather than the executable, and it will go run the other makefile or not, as needed.

Comment: a command in your top level makefile:

docs:
   $(MAKE) -C docs all

will do the trick, I've revised the answer for more clarity